# Display a ListView on a Home Widget with AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, listview, widget

I would like to create a Home Widget containing a ListView, but I don't know if this is possible and if it is, how to do it.
I was using a ListActivity and it was pretty simple, but can't figure out a way to do it using AppWidgetProvider.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

This is unfortunately not possible, app widgets do not support ListViews.

Comment: So what's the best way to display a list of things in an app widget?

Answer (score 1):

ListView is support from API level 11 onwards.